# Why do some DynamoDB Queries take a very long time?

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, amazon-dynamodb

We have a Lambda that queries from a DynamoDB table (very small, probably 1 megabyte) in total size. We see that most of our queries take about 50-100ms but then we have some queries that take seconds, or 45 seconds, or even past a minute. Our Lambda is set to time out at 27 seconds, so the client never even sees a response.

Is there a reason why DynamoDB would take so long to query? Our setup is "On-Demand" as well. We are using NodeJS as well. Our Lambdas have 2gb of memory.

Our architecture: `API Gateway-> Authorizer(cache every hour)-> Lambda that queries the DynamoDB table`.

Comment: Any patterns you can see across the requests which take longer? Sort keys? Is your Lambda in a VPC? Any code? We need more information.

Comment: Can you post your query and maybe a screenshot of the metrics graph for query latency?